# How to check if the device has front and rear facing cameras?

Tags: android, android-camera

I need to detect if the phone has a front facing camera, and if so, I need to calculate the megapixels. The same thing goes for a rear facing camera.

I know how to get the megapixels of a "Camera" object, but I don't know how to check for the other things.

P.s.: I would also be nice if you know a way to check if the Camera has flash or not, and other cool statistics about the camera

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#getNumberOfCameras() , introduced in API lvl 9. This gets you the number of cameras

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.CameraInfo.html contains information of its facing direction.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#getPictureSize() is megapixels, if counted

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#getFlashMode() returns null if no flash..

many other parameters can be gotten from the camera object too

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html has step by step instructions for using camera. You can follow these instructions if you understand any object oriented language.

Comment: yes, i can get the number of cameras, but, how can i instantiate each camera and to check the facing direction of both cameras? code example will be nice, i can't find the way to achieve it

Comment: can't write code with baby in one hand.  The API documentation has examples.

Comment: thanks for the links, but i still can't find the way to know how to get info from front camera and how to get info from rear camera. I just know how to get number of cameras and info from one of the cameras. But i dont know how to instantiate the camera object of the front camera and the camera object of the rear camera. I can't find that in these links

Comment: Both cameras have their own ID, which you give to the open(int). When you open() the camera, you get an Camera-object. Opened with f.e open(0), you get fron camera and with open(1), you get rear camera, or viceversa. After that, you call the getPictureSize, etc of each of these objects to get the attribute of rear and front camera. And if I remember correctly, you can only have one camera opened at a time. You need to release one to use the other one.

Comment: mmm, nice! going to check it !

Comment: I would have given a + if it actually showed how to do it. Should be just a fast snippit (as I've written it years ago before..)

Answer (score 4):

I always try to create helpers 
check if you have a front Camera:

```
public static boolean checkCameraFront(Context context) {
    if(context.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FRONT)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Check if you have Camera in your device

```
public static boolean checkCameraRear() {
    int numCamera = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();
    if(numCamera > 0) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you help me, I got stuck in the condition where I have Front.camera but no rear camera. How can i check that?